# How to auto link to the facebook page after submit button was clicked by Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a xamarin form which enable user to key in User Id and password, and there is a submit button provided in the interface.

If in **python** code the way to code for the facebook to auto open and fill in the detail are in following:

```
    br.get('https://www.facebook.com')
    user=br.find_element_by_css_selector('#login-form-username')
    user.send_keys('sj@hotmail.com')
    password=br.find_element_by_css_selector('#login-form-password')
    password.send_keys('helloword')
```

How to code in order to open the facebook page after the button was click in xamarin-android?

Comment: Do you want to open the facebook application or open a webpage with facebook as the link?

Comment: @diomonogatari is webpage with facebook

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you want to open facebook app, this code works on Android

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.facebook.katana"));
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(intent);
```

**ALSO :**  add one line before `startActivity(intent);`

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

**NOTE THAT** com.facebook.android is the package name for the Facebook SDK. The Facebook app is com.facebook.katana.

If you want to open the facebook webpage then you will want to do something like this:

```
intent.button.Click += delegate {
   var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("https://www.facebook.com");
   var intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView, uri);
   StartActivity (intent);
};
```